# Laravel: how to seed Baum's nested set?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'd like to seed one of my tables that is a nested set. I'm using Baum's nested set, which provides an easy way to see a nested set: https://github.com/etrepat/baum#seeding

How do I use Baum from `/database/seeds/`? Based on the Laravel documention, I would need to extend the `Seeder` class in order for seeding to work. However, in order to use Baum's methods, I need to extend `Baum\Node`.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well, If you can use the Baum model directly and it's ok for your purposes, I suggest to use it. This way you have easy access to baum's functions. I use my Baum model directly in the seed, without extending the seeder class.
Here's a little snippet :

```
class BusinessUnitTableSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        public function run()
        {
            $admin = DB::table('user')->where('login_name', '=', 'superadmin')->pluck('id');
            $root = BusinessUnit::create([
                    'name' => 'Headquarters',
                    'created_by' => $admin,
                    'updated_by' => $admin,
                    'owned_by'   => $admin
                ]);
            $user = \User::find($admin);
            $user->business_unit = $root->id;
            $user->save();
            $child1 = $root->children()->create([
                    'name' => 'Business unit 1',
                    'created_by' => $admin,
                    'updated_by' => $admin,
                    'owned_by'   => $admin
            ]);
            $child2 = $child1->children()->create([
                    'name' => 'Business unit 2',
                    'created_by' => $admin,
                    'updated_by' => $admin,
                    'owned_by'   => $admin
            ]);


        }
    }
```

**UPD:** To find out where to place your seeds and how to call theme, please refer the docs directly [here](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding). Making the model is extremely fast. so I would recomend you to do so, it would cause less actions to do further. The model must be placed at the `models` directory, and the fast snippet of model extending the Baum would be

```
class YourModel extends extends Baum\Node
{
 /**
   * Column name to store the reference to parent's node.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $parentColumn = 'parent_id';

  /**
   * Column name for left index.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $leftColumn = 'lft';

  /**
   * Column name for right index.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $rightColumn = 'rgt';

  /**
   * Column name for depth field.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $depthColumn = 'depth';

/**
         * Table name.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'your_baum_table';

}
```

And then use it directly in your seed. That is all .
Also, my preferable way of adding seeds to the app is using the migrations:

1. Create the seed
2. Create the migration
3. in function `up()` just add `Artisan::call('db:seed',['--class'=> 'YourDesiredSeed'])`.

This way I can add demo or real data on already working apps.

Comment: Can you please show me how the class containing this method is defined? And then, how is this run() method called?

Comment: Please keep in mind that I am new to Laravel. I'm learning how to seed the database and use `php artisan db:seed` command to seed my DB. I have completed my migration files and currently working on seeding. I have not done any of the models, yet.

Comment: I have added an update to my answer. Please feel free to ask questions

Comment: Do you have documentation about Step #3? Is that supposed to call a method in the Baum model?

Comment: No, It's a simple migration file, that as you mentioned you've already performed. Consider it as a new migration file ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm now very confused. How do I access Baum's methods from the Seeder? Your example extends the Seeder class, not Baum\Node. I thought you were suggesting to create a Baum model that will have a method to seed, and that method would be called from the Seeder's run() method. I was asking how to do that, which is what I thought your #3 step does.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie BusinessUnitTableSeeder extends Seeder, but BusinessUnit probably extends Baum\Node

Answer (score 0):

> I used for my products
>
> Just I do it using an array with the variables used in baum.
>
> I created a model using:
>
> **php artisan baum:install Product**
>
> this will create a model (I changed to app folder)and migration.
>   Just update migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration {

  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function up() {
    Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table) {
      // These columns are needed for Baum's Nested Set implementation to work.
      // Column names may be changed, but they *must* all exist and be modified
      // in the model.
      // Take a look at the model scaffold comments for details.
      // We add indexes on parent_id, lft, rgt columns by default.
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable()->index();
      $table->integer('lft')->nullable()->index();
      $table->integer('rgt')->nullable()->index();
      $table->integer('depth')->nullable();

      // Add needed columns here (f.ex: name, slug, path, etc.)
      // $table->string('name', 255);

      $table->string('name',500);
      $table->string('slug');
      $table->string('brand',255);
      $table->string('sku',255)->unique();
      $table->string('description',1000);
      $table->integer('quantity');
      $table->decimal('price',6,2);
      $table->boolean('badge',2);
      $table->string('image1',255);
      $table->boolean('visible',2);
      $table->string('created_at');
      $table->string('updated_at');

      });
  }

  /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function down() {
    Schema::drop('products');
  }

}
```

Then just do your seed for using for example.

```
use App\Product;
use Baum\Node;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ProductTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
   public function run()
    {
        $data = array(
            [
                'name'          => 'product1',
                'slug'          => 'slug blablabla',
                'brand'         => 'brand',
                'sku'           => 'xxxxxx',
                'description'   => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                'quantity'      => 100,
                'price'         => 275.00,
                'badge'         => 1,
                'image1'        => 'xxx.jpeg',
                'visible'       => 1,
                'created_at'    => new DateTime,
                'updated_at'    => new DateTime,
            ],
        );
        Product::insert($data);
    }
}
```